# Get all elements beginning with a particular string

Tags: php, arrays

I need to list a query's results ( a list of companies) in alphabetical order.

Due to the nature of the solution required I need to have all separate (all beginning with 'A' separate to all beginning with 'B' separate to all beginning with 'C' etc...) so I can't just list the results alphabetically directly....I need to create 26 arrays, one for each letter.

I have put all results (from the query to select all companies) into an array and now I need to divide them into 26 arrays.

$companies = array(company 1, company 2,....company n);

now I am looking for (hoping there is) a built-in PHP array function:

$companies_beginning_with_A = some_array_function('A', $companies);

I could not find such a function...does anyone know of one? If not how would you recommend I go about this?

Answer (score 1):

[fnmatch()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fnmatch.php) with [array_filter()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) is a pretty powerful combination

```
$search = 'A*';
$companies_beginning_with_A = array_filter(
    $companies,
    function($value) use ($search) {
        return fnmatch($search, $value);
    }
);
```

Note the use of the wildcard in the search term

So

```
$splitCompanies = array();
foreach(range('A', 'Z') as $letter) {
    $search = $letter . '*';
    $splitCompanies[$letter] = array_filter(
        $companies,
        function($value) use ($search) {
            return fnmatch($search, $value);
        }
    );
}
```

will build you a multi-dimensional array top-level indexed by letter

Answer (score 0):

You can do the below, putting the results into one array quite simply:

```
$sortedCompanies = array();
foreach($companies as $company){
    $firstLetter = substr($company, 0, 1);
    $sortedCompanies[$firstLetter][] = $company;
}
```